# Customising the wso2 publisher page to show apis as a list

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to 1) customise wso2 api manager publisher and store to show apis as a list , 2) add a additional link on the publisher page to help user with the guidelines.
Thanks and Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make changes in it's existing jag apps which are located `repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\modules\`. For reference of jaggery framework, you can follow this [documentation](http://jaggeryjs.org/).

Also make sure you save this changes in your versioning system & deployment/migration scripts. As this changes are required if you are doing migration in future.

Comment: Could not find application directory or file under repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\site\blocks\

Comment: I hope you are checking into home directory of your `WSO2-APIM` (it could be like `/opt/WSO2/wso2-APIM-2.6.0/`)

Comment: yes .i can findthe path till repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\site\blocks\ but not the application folder or directory. I am using 2.6.0